# How to order Django QuerySet in specific order based off model field values?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sql-order-by

I have the following (simplified) model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    TYPE_SOMETHING = 0
    TYPE_SOMETHING_ELSE = 1
    TYPE_ANOTHER = 2

    type = models.SmallIntegerField()
    # other model fields
```

I'd like to perform a query such as:

```
MyModel.objects.all()
```

However, the QuerySet has to be ordered by the `type` attribute, but in a specific order:

```
1. TYPE_SOMETHING_ELSE
2. TYPE_SOMETHING
3. TYPE_ANOTHER
```

This is not an ascending or descending sort.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe a workaround, `MyModel.objects.get(type=MyModel.TYPE_SOMETHING_ELSE)` `MyModel.objects.get(type=MyModel.TYPE_SOMETHING)` `MyModel.objects.get(type=MyModel.TYPE_ANOTHER)` i.e. three queries instead of one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because Django's `SortedDict` is deprecated, I used a similar answer to Annop and Savad KP:

```
import collections
MyModel.objects.extra(
    select=collections.SortedDict([(
        'types',
        'CASE WHEN type = %d THEN 0 ',
        'WHEN type = %d THEN 1',
        'WHEN type = %s THEN 2',
        'END' % (
            MyModel.TYPE_ANOTHER,
            MyModel.TYPE_SOMETHING,
            MyModel.TYPE_SOMETHING_ELSE
        ))
    ])
).order_by('types')
```

Quite simple in the end :)

Comment: `collections.SortedDict()` gives an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @planetp what are you passing to the `SortedDict` constructor?

Answer (score 1):

We can sort `queryset` with the help of *django* **`SortedDict`** 
For more about `SortedDict` please go throgh [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.datastructures.SortedDict) doc

```
from django.utils.datastructures import SortedDict

MyModel.objects.extra( select=SortedDict([('type',
  'case when type = %d then 2 when type = %d then 1 else 0  end' %
  (MyModel.TYPE_SOMETHING_ELSE, MyModel.TYPE_SOMETHING, MyModel.TYPE_ANOTHER))]) )
  .order_by('type')
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I published a [tiny third-party](http://django-reorder.readthedocs.io/) that helps fix this issue by generating the `CASE WHEN ...` SQL statements for you.

With this library, you can do:

```
from django_reorder.reorder import reorder

MyModel.objects.order_by(reorder(type=[TYPE_SOMETHING_ELSE, TYPE_SOMETHING, TYPE_ANOTHER]))
```

And your queryset will be sorted the way you want.

Comment: But where do you actually call the imported `reorder`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this:

`from django.utils.datastructures import SortedDict`

```
MyModel.objects.extra(select=SortedDict([('types',
'case when type = %d then 2 when type = %d then 1 else 0 end' % 
(MyModel.TYPE_SOMETHING_ELSE,MyModel.TYPE_SOMETHING))])
).order_by('types')
```

The sql query behind this is

```
SELECT (case when type = 1 then 2 when type = 0 then 1 else 0  end) AS "type", "testapp_mymodel"."id", "testapp_mymodel"."types" FROM "testapp_mymodel" ORDER BY "types" ASC
```

And the SortedDict is just used for preserving the order of select option

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `order_by()` method with a [`Case()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) expression:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, IntegerField    

queryset = MyModel.objects.order_by(Case(
    When(type=MyModel.TYPE_ANOTHER, then=0),
    When(type=MyModel.TYPE_SOMETHING, then=1),
    When(type=MyModel.TYPE_SOMETHING_ELSE, then=2),
    output_field=IntegerField()))
```

This would be a better option than using [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) with raw SQL which Django docs recommend against.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question properly, you want to store a set of integers but have them retrieved from the database in a non-standard order. I'm not sure exactly how your constant variables fit into your schema, but my suggestion is that you should sideline the variable names by storing them separately in a list which you can access via their index. For example:

```
choices_list = [TYPE_SOMETHING, TYPE_SOMETHING_ELSE, TYPE_ANOTHER]

TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (0, 1),
    (1, 0),
    (2, 3)
)

class MyModel(models.Model):

    type = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

    def get_type_display(self):
        return choices_list[self.type.id]
```

If you wanted to take it further, you could override `SmallIntegerField` to return those values automatically.